# Getting empty images from server

Tags: php, laravel, image, .htaccess, cpanel

I have images on my server, some of them uploaded using Flutter (Dart) and others uploaded using Laravel (PHP). The problem is that **most of the images are empty when accessing them but they exist on the server and I can see them and open them from cpanel.**
Examples of empty images:

https://clinicalibya.com/images/advertisements/1617909384cpd%20device%20logo.png

https://clinicalibya.com/images/receipts/1617913147scaled_db3b4b6b-eb71-4983-a8fa-14dbdf826b677185714734801956022.jpg

Notice: I am not getting any 404 errors. The images are blank in the browser and when retrieving an image in Flutter, it says that the image is empty.

Here is the .htaccess file content:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Handle Authorization Header

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$

RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|robots\.txt)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/

RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 3000
   php_value max_input_time 6000
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 4G
   php_value post_max_size 128M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 3000
   php_value max_input_time 6000
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 4G
   php_value post_max_size 128M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Can you  specify the path on the server to the folder where the image is located? 
something like this? `project_root/public/images/receipts/1617913147scaled_db3b4b6b-eb71-4983-a8fa-14dbdf826b677185714734801956022.jpg` ? or in storage folder?

If storage - than you need link folders: `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Is the URL to the "empty" images you've stated the actual direct filepath to those images? Do you have a front-end caching proxy that is perhaps catching these requests?

Comment: @yaroslaww yes the path is right. I haven't used storage.

Comment: @MrWhite yes the url represents the actual direct filepath. No front-end caching proxy.

Comment: @AbdulrazakZakieh
Why you use this condition?

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/`
`RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]` 


By default DocumentRoot should be `...project_root/public`

Comment: there default htaccess https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/.htaccess . + You can add bottom additional CPanel content if need

Comment: @yaroslawww Thanks for your help. I replaced the content of .htacess with the one you mentioned and I am getting 500 error now for all the pages.

Comment: ...any change to the image request? Is this also now returning 500 response?

Comment: Yes. All of the website and all images give the same error. You can click on the images in the question to see the error.

Comment: What happens if you remove your `.htaccess` file entirely?

Comment: I got 404 for the website and the blank images

Comment: Ok, something a bit odd going on... is this for _all_ images? Are file permissions/ownership set correctly? What about images with a short filename? What about other file types? eg. `.txt` files in the same directory? Presumably you don't have any other `.htaccess` files? Do you have access to the server config? If you enable directory listings just for this (these) specific directory (ie. `Options +Indexes` in a `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory) what do you see when you request the directory?

Comment: All the permissions are the same for all images 644. For the length of the image name, here is a link to an image that works:
https://clinicalibya.com/images/advertisements/1609947389Hangman.png
and this for one that is empty:
https://clinicalibya.com/images/advertisements/1617287813Hangman.png
and both of them has the same length. Both of images can be downloaded from the cpanel and both of them are fine.

Comment: For the .htaccess, I found one in the root folder, one in the public_html and one in the public folder in public_html as well. All have the same value. I tried to delete them as well but that did not help.
The whole thing was working fine on local host.

Comment: Well, your server is certainly treating those two "images" differently. I didn't just notice this before, but for the images that appear "blank" your server is returning an incorrect `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` header and a `Vary: User-Agent` header (as well as different `Cache-Control` headers, etc). This would seem to suggest you _do_ have some kind of front-end (caching) proxy?? "I found one in the root folder, one in the public_html" - is "root" not public_html? Do you mean _above_ the document root? All `.htaccess` files _potentially_ apply along the filesystem path.

Comment: I have not implemented any front-end caching proxy. Would you please guide me to know whether I have it and how to get rid of it if it exists.
For the .htaccess, I meant there is one in the folder that contains public_html as well.

Comment: 1. Can you confirm your DocumentRoot = ...project_root/public ?
2. What if you move image `/images/receipts/1617913147scaled_db3b4b6b-eb71-4983-a8fa-14dbdf826b677185714734801956022.jpg` to this path? `/images/1617913147scaled_db3b4b6b-eb71-4983-a8fa-14dbdf826b677185714734801956022.jpg` ?
3. What is you will move image `/images/clinic.png` to subfolder  `/images/receipts/clinic.png`?

Comment: yes the document root is public_html/public/...
for the images, moving them outside the subfolder to images folder did not affect them. However, moving images from images folder to subfolder made them blank and getting them back outside made them working again.
Means /images/receipts/clinic.png did not work but getting it back to /images/clinic.png worked.
Thanks for your time. Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I found two images folders one in public_html and one in public_html/public. The working images exist in public_html folder and the images I am trying to use are in public_html/public. I am accessing images like this: /images/name.png and it refers images folder in public_html instead of public_html/public
The thing I could not explain is getting empty pages instead of 404 error and why is /images/ refers public/images on my local host & public_html/images on the host.
The problem is solved by accessing the images 
like /public/images/name.png. Thank you both for your help and time.